# Windows 10 Bluetooth sound quality is still poor?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

My bluetooth headphones are really good, they sound amazing on my phone but about 2x as bad when connected to my PC. It will not allow me to go past CD quality. My problem is **NOT** hands free telephony, It is windows bluetooth quality. Could this be changed or is it a problem with my Bluetooth Card?

-Sorry for bad grammar/sentence structure english is not my first language

Comment: All I could suggest here is an alternative Bluetooth adapter (USB connector and Bluetooth antenna). This will help you determine if the problem is hardware.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to check in Windows 10 is that you are choosing the best audio output option.

Windows will often have both 'Headset' and 'Headphones' options for the one connected device. Head**phones** gives better sound.

Click the Sound icon in the notification area, click 'Select Playback Device' (or click the arrow), then see what options are available. Make sure you choose the Head**phones** rather than the lower quality Head**set** option.